# To validate DOB(Date of birth) column and AGE column is correct using SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, db2, date

I'm stuck and need help to validate a special DOB format with age in the same table where it will only return the DOB that is not true as per validation with AGE.

Tried to find in other thread but it seems more towards JavaScript and programming side. Please help me what is the SQL statement to get that expected output:

Table: Customer

```
Column 1: NUM

Column 2: DOB 

Column 3: AGE
```

| NUM | DOB | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 851201888888 | 36 |
| 2 | 701128999999 | 51 |
| 3 | 910303777777 | 50 |
| 4 | 950202555555 | 70 |

**DOB format = YYMMDDXXXXXX (where X is any random num that can be ignored)

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

No DOB AGE

3 910303777777 50

4 950202555555 70

Thanks guys!

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to store DOB and Age both unless it's a trivia question :). Shouldn't Age be calculated based on DOB and is kind of nondeterministic?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH t1 (NUM, DOB, AGE) AS (
  VALUES(3, '910303777777', 50)
),
t2 AS (
SELECT DOB
     , CASE WHEN substr(DOB, 1, 2) > substr(CURRENT date, 3, 2)
        THEN '19' || substr(DOB,1,2) || '-' || substr(DOB,3,2) || '-' || substr(DOB,5,2)
        ELSE '20' || substr(DOB,1,2) || '-' || substr(DOB,3,2) || '-' || substr(DOB,5,2)
       END AS dob_date
     , age      
  FROM t1
)
SELECT DOB
     , years_between(CURRENT date, dob_date) AS Age_by_DOB
     , age
  FROM t2
 WHERE years_between(CURRENT date, dob_date) <> age
```

Note: This will also return the first row as the person is not yet 36. You have not provided enough information so you might need to adjust this query to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand the question, but it seems like you are looking for Concatenate (Concat).

```
Select Table.*, Concat (Num, ' ', DOB, ' ', Age) as 'No DOB AGE'
From Table
```

Hopefully that helps!